# Merge-sorting in R using lists instead of vectors

Tags: r, list, mergesort

So i've written this basic code that sorts a list using the well-known merge-sorting algorithm, i've defined two functions mergelists that compares and merges the elements and mergesort that divides the list into single elements:

```
mergelists <- function(a,b) {
al <- length(a)
bl <- length(b)
r <- numeric(al+bl)
ai <- 1
bi <- 1
j <- 1
while((ai<=al) && (bi<=bl)) {
if(a[ai]<b[bi]) {
r[j] <- a[ai]
ai <- ai+1
} else {
r[j] <- b[bi]
bi <- bi+1
}
j <- j+1
}
if(ai<=al) r[j:(al+bl)] <- a[ai:al]
else if(bi<=bl) r[j:(al+bl)] <- b[bi:bl]
return(r)
}


mergesort <- function(x) {
l <- length(x)
if(l>1) {
p <- ceiling(l/2)
a <- mergesort(x[1:p])
b <- mergesort(x[(p+1):l])
return(mergelists(a,b))
}
return(x)
}
```

this seems to work fine for the examples i used so far, for example:

```
> mergesort(c(11,10,9,15,6,12,17,8,19,7))
[1] 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 15 17 19
```

now for the sake of some research i'm doing, i want to change this code to work with R-lists and not vectors, the lists are usually defined as following:

```
> list(number=10,data=c(10,5,8,2))
$number
[1] 10
$data
[1] 10 5 8 2
```

data represents here the vector and number is the number of comparaisons.
After the change i imagine that the program should give me something like this:

```
>mergelists(list(number=8,data=c(1,3,5,8,9,10)),list(number=5,data=c(2,4,6,7)))
$number
[1] 20
$data
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

> mergesort(c(11,10,9,15,6,12,17,8,19,7))
$number
[1] 22
$data
[1] 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 15 17 19
```

the 20 here is basically 8 + 5 + 7, because 7 comparaisons would be necessary to merge the two sorted lists, but i don't know how to do this because i have a little experience with R-lists. i would appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Is `$number` meant to restrict the number of comparisons? If so, I don't understand why the inputs have this property. IOW, what does `number=8` in the input mean? If the respective `data` is pre-sorted, then this might be the output from the previous sort, but if it is potentially unsorted, then what should this be?

Comment: actually this is what i'm trying to understand too .. as i said i have little experience with R-Lists, but i found in online guides that R-Lists are generated this way, with 'number' being the number of comparaisons, so i imagine $number 20 is just 7+8+5 with 7 being the number of comparaisons needed to merge those lists, but i don't know what 8 and 5 are ..

Comment: "*R-lists are generated this way*" makes no sense to me. `list(data=c(1,3,5))` is a list but nothing inherent to a `list` includes adding arbitrary elements like `number`. From where are you getting the list in that format?

Comment: in this example : list(number=10,data=c(10,5,8,2)) the 10 is just chosen randomly and it has no effect, it's just an example of how a list with a precised field is defined in R, this 'number=' fields are only relevent with the implementation of mergelists and mergesort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The starting point for any vector `vec` is `list(number = 0, data = vec)`, where `number` is 0 because it as taken 0 comparisons to start with an unsorted vector.

You first need to modify `mergelists` to deal with two lists, simply by adding the indexing and then reforming the list at the end.

```
mergelists <- function(a,b) {
  firstn <- a$number + b$number
  a <- a$data
  b <- b$data
  al <- length(a)
  bl <- length(b)
  r <- numeric(al+bl)
  ai <- 1
  bi <- 1
  j <- 1
  while((ai<=al) && (bi<=bl)) {
    if(a[ai]<b[bi]) {
      r[j] <- a[ai]
      ai <- ai+1
    } else {
      r[j] <- b[bi]
      bi <- bi+1
    }
    j <- j+1
  }
  if(ai<=al) r[j:(al+bl)] <- a[ai:al]
  else if(bi<=bl) r[j:(al+bl)] <- b[bi:bl]
  return(list(number = firstn + j - 1L, data = r))
}
mergelists(list(number=8,data=c(1,3,5,8,9,10)), list(number=5,data=c(2,4,6,7)))
# $number
# [1] 20
# $data
#  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Now that you have the "base function" defined, you need the calling function to generate the enhanced vector (`list`) and pass it accordingly. This function can easily be improved for efficiency, but I think its recursive properties are sound.

```
mergesort <- function(x) {
  # this first guarantees that if called with a vector, it is list-ified,
  # but if called with a list (i.e., every other time in the recursion),
  # the argument is untouched
  if (! is.list(x)) x <- list(number = 0, data = x)
  l <- length(x$data)
  if (l > 1) {
    p <- ceiling(l/2)
    # the `within(...)` trick is a sneaky trick, can easily be
    # handled with pre-assignment/subsetting
    a <- mergesort(within(x, { data <- data[1:p]; }))
    b <- mergesort(within(x, { data <- data[(p+1):l]; }))
    return(mergelists(a,b))
  }
  return(x)
}
mergesort(c(11,10,9,15,6,12,17,8,19,7))
# $number
# [1] 22
# $data
#  [1]  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 15 17 19
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but you didn't change anything in the first code, it always gives the error: 'Error in a[ai] < b[bi]: comparaison of these types is not implemented'

Comment: hehe, bad paste, check now

Comment: As [has been commented before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44618337/defining-exponential-distribution-in-r-to-estimate-probabilities#comment76228796_44618414), please "accept" this answer by clicking on the checkmark to the left of it.

Comment: oh one last thing : what are a$number and a$data ? i mean what they do define ? and here: return(list(number = firstn + j - 1L, data = r)) what is the '1L' ?

Comment: `1L` is an `integer` of 1 (vice a floating-point `numeric` of 1.0), that's all, I prefer to be explicit in type expectations, even if R is rather forgiving (and assuming). As far as `$number` and `$data`, I have no idea, it was provided by you in your problem statement. There is nothing in R (that I'm familiar with) that mandates this convention. (Frankly, I've never seen anything use it, either.)